# How do I check if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, append

I would like to append some text to a `<span>` after checking whether or not a checkbox has been checked. I have multiple checkboxes on the page and I only want to append the `<span>` once. All the solutions I have seen don't seem to work for me. I have tried to check by:

```
if ($('input:checkbox[name="skills"]').prop('checked')) {
   $('#filter-7').append($('#headingSkills a').text());
}
```

And:

```
if ($('input:checkbox[name="skills"]').is(':checked')) {
    $('#filter-7').append($('#headingSkills a').text());
}
```

Neither seem to work and I don't want to add the append() to my change function because it appends the span multiple times and I only want it to be appended when the checkbox is checked once.

Here is my change function:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="skills"]').change(function () {
    var values = $('input:checkbox[name="skills"]:checked').map(function () {
      return '<span><button class="remove-selection" value="' + this.value.trim() + '"></button> ' + this.value.trim() + '</span>';
    }).get();

    $('#filter-7').append($('#headingSkills a').text());

    $('#filter-7-result').empty().append(values);
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" id="button-7" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#skillsCollapse"
                   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="skillsCollapse">
                    Skills
    </a>
</h4>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Accounting">Accounting</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Administration">Administration</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Budgeting">Budgeting</label>
<label>
```

When someone clicks on one of the checkboxes above, I want to append the button title (Skills) to:

`<span id="filter-7"></span>`

I know this a commonly asked question but nothing I have tried seems to work.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/085vg97d/. What exactly is the issue? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: if it's in your change function, you can just use `this.checked` to see if your current input is checked or not

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry I should have added my HTML structure, I have updated my question to include it as the text I am trying to append is not the value from the checkbox but from a button.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for editing, but your code still works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cofkqn1a/

Comment: I am trying to attempt to append the value of "Skills" to the span when a checkbox is selected, however with the append being in the change function it gets appended every time a checkbox is checked and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @NeelamKhan u can use html() or text() instead

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/neelam_cite/xw420s3g/2/ is an updated fiddle with the problem, you can see everytime a checkbox is clicked "Skills" is appended multiple times, I want to append it just once. To do that I was checking to see if the checkbox has been checked but wasn't able to as none of my checks were working @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So change `append()` to `text()`: https://jsfiddle.net/4eag3wh1/

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan that fixed it! I can accept that as the answer if you want to answer the question or I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending the text node every time this logic runs. If you only want the value to be shown once as each value is selected use `text()` instead of `append()`:

```
$('#filter-7').text($('#headingSkills a').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is(':checked')` for checking if checkbox is checked

```js
$('.check').change(function(e){
 var text='';
   $('.check').each(function(e){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       text='checked';
   })
   $('.content').html(text) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="content"></span>
<input type="checkbox" class="check">one
<input type="checkbox" class="check">two
<input type="checkbox" class="check">three
<input type="checkbox" class="check">Four
```

Comment: Given that the OP's code already works I don't see the benefit of answering this until they've clarified the problem. Also note that their current logic is more efficient that this